# Deriving a special character from an integer

Tags: c#, character

I'm experimenting with some ways to save compact data, and I decided to try and save integer values to a string. What I am looking to do is take a number that has been put into a function, and turn it into a character (ex. alt + 50). How to I get special characters in script from an integer? Example of what I have/want to accomplish:

```
void saveID(int id){
     stringOfIDs + (alt + id); //how do I call this in script?
}
```

Comment: _I decided to try and save integer values to a string_ But WHY?

Comment: You are likely to actually want Base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how to get the Unicode character with the given ordinal.

You can do that by casting the integer to a `char`.

If the integer is more than 2<sup>16</sup>, you'll need to deal with surrogate pairs; call `Char.ConvertFromUtf32()`.

If the character is in the ranges used for surrogate pairs, you will get invalid Unicode.

Comment: Thanks! Huge mind block didn't thing of them as chars:

stringOfIDs += (char)id;